# Yarmulke with fur rim

Tags: clothing, wedding, chasidut-hasidism, head-covering

I came across this picture of a Gur Chasid at his wedding wearing a black yarmulke with a sort of fur rim (not the spodik).

Why does the yarmulke/kippah have this fur rim. Is this because he is of rabbinic familly?
[image]

Comment: Hi @Jim and welcome to Mi Yodeya! If you are referring to his hat that is a shreimal/spodik

Comment: @Dov thank you for your comment. But i am reffering to his actual yarmulke/kippah which seems to have a fur rim.

Comment: Fur is expensive and a luxury item that signifies royalty (which happens to be the reason shtreimlach are made from fur). He's at his wedding and wants to look nice. That's the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During auspicious occasions, many people, especially Chasidim like to bring or wear an article of clothing that once belonged to a Tzadik. It is thought that the good deeds of that person will inspire greater prayer and bring blessing to the couple in their merit.

It seems that the protaganist of the photo is wearing an ancient yarmulke (under his own yarmulke) probally of a great ancestor or rebbe.